# Mock ViewDataDictionary with MVC Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I am wanting to build a unit test for an ActionFilterAttribute derived class. 
 My Unit test needs to look at values stored in the controller viewbag and in the written cookies.

The code below doesn't work as I can't instantiate the ViewDataDictionary without passing in some other variables that aren't very clear.

Thanks
Mark

```
    public class MockedHttpContext : DefaultHttpContext
    {
        public static string NextBody;
        public static IHeaderDictionary NextHeaders;
        public static IRequestCookieCollection NextCookieCollection;

        public MockedHttpContext()
        {
            NextCookieCollection = null;
        }

        protected override HttpRequest InitializeHttpRequest()
        {
            return new MockedHttpRequest(NextBody, NextHeaders, NextCookieCollection, this);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class MockedHttpRequest : HttpRequest, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IHeaderDictionary headers;
        private IRequestCookieCollection cookieCollection;
        private bool disposed = false;
        private Stream body;

        public MockedHttpRequest(string body, IHeaderDictionary headers, IRequestCookieCollection cookieCollection, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            this.headers = headers;
            this.cookieCollection = cookieCollection;
            this.body = new MemoryStream();
            this.HttpContext = httpContext;

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.body, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, 256, true))
            {
                writer.Write(body ?? string.Empty);
                writer.Flush();
                this.body.Position = 0;
            }

            if (this.body.CanRead)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Here!");
            }
        }

        ~MockedHttpRequest()
        {
            this.Dispose(false);
        }

        public override string Method { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override string Scheme { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override bool IsHttps { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override HostString Host { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override PathString PathBase { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override PathString Path { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override QueryString QueryString { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override IQueryCollection Query { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override string Protocol { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override HttpContext HttpContext { get; }

        public override IHeaderDictionary Headers => this.headers;

        public override IRequestCookieCollection Cookies
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cookieCollection;
            }

            set
            {
                this.cookieCollection = value;
            }
        }

        public override long? ContentLength { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override string ContentType { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override Stream Body
        {
            get { return this.body; }
            set { this.body = value; }
        }

        public override bool HasFormContentType => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override IFormCollection Form { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public override Task<IFormCollection> ReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (this.disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (disposing)
            {
                this.body.Dispose();
            }

            this.disposed = true;
        }
```

```
    public abstract class ActionFilterAttributeTest
    {
        protected abstract ActionFilterAttribute OnCreateAttribute(string testName);

        protected virtual void OnValidateResults(string testName, ActionExecutingContext context) { }

        protected async Task ExecuteTest(string testName, IHeaderDictionary headerDictionary, IRequestCookieCollection cookieCollection, Type resultType)
        {
            ViewDataDictionary viewbag = null; // new ViewDataDictionary();
            //A sample attribute in the standard template can be any action attribute
            ActionFilterAttribute function = new EUPrivacyAttribute();
            var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();

            MockedHttpContext.NextHeaders = headerDictionary;
            MockedHttpContext.NextCookieCollection = cookieCollection;
            var httpContextMock = new MockedHttpContext(serviceProvider);

            // httpContextMock.Request.Query = new QueryCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues> { }); // if you are reading any properties from the query parameters

            var actionContext = new ActionContext(
                httpContextMock,
                Mock.Of<RouteData>(),
                Mock.Of<ActionDescriptor>(),
                modelState);

            var actionExecutingContext = new ActionExecutingContext(
                actionContext,
                new List<IFilterMetadata>(),
                new Dictionary<string, object>(),
                Mock.Of<Controller>(a => a.ViewData == viewbag))
            {
                Result = new OkResult(), // It will return OK unless during code execution you change this when by condition
            };
            Mock<ActionExecutingContext> context = new Mock<ActionExecutingContext>();

            function.OnActionExecuting(actionExecutingContext);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionExecutingContext.Result, resultType);
            //I now want to validate the controller viewbag contents
        }
    }
```